# Pass a function into another component, and it doesn't run

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to enable and disable a button according to when a value changes. With that said, I have create a model that may look something like:

```
export class Model{
    label:string='';
    isEnabled:Function=()=>true;
}
```

`component1` that may look something like:

```
@Component({
    selector:'c1',
    template:`
     <button class="btn btn-default> [ngModel]="{'disabled':model.isEnabled()}">{{label}}</button>
    `
})
export class Component1{
   @Input() model:Model;
}
```

`Component2` may look something like:

```
@Component({
selector:'c2',
template:`
 <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="onClick()">Click me</button>
 <c1 [model]=model></c1>
`
})
export class Component2 implements OnInit{
  enabled:boolean=false;
  model:Model;

  ngOnInit(){
   this.model = new Model();
   model.label = "Something Cool";
   model.isEnabled = ()=> this.enabled;
  }

  onClick(){
     this.enabled = !this.enabled;
  }
}
```

where ideally when I click the first button the second become enabled.

So my issue is that the function is never fired and the c1 button is never disabled. Can anyone tell me why this wouldn't happen?

Answer (score -1):

try something like this:

```
export class Model{
    label:string='';
    isEnabled:boolean:true;
}
```

Component 1:

```
@Component({
    selector:'c1',
    template:`
     <button class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!model.isEnabled">{{model.label}}</button>
    `
})
export class Component1{
   @Input() model:Model;
}
```

Component 2:

```
export class Component2 implements OnInit{
  enabled:boolean=false;
  model:Model;

  ngOnInit(){
   this.model = new Model();
   this.model.label = "Something Cool";
   this.model.isEnabled = false;
  }

  onClick(){
     this.model.isEnabled = !this.model.isEnabled;

  }
}
```

In any case you should read the basic angular tutorial :)